# Sound Using HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (Cylon Linux, more specifically, which just uses UBUNTU updates). When I connect my HDMI to my Panasonic flat screen television, sound still comes from my computer and in sound settings only "Speakers" is an output device. How can I make it realize it's using HDMI, to play sound on the television, and not my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Your video card may not be passing the sound through HDMI.  HDMI can trasmit sound and video, but most PC video cards are for exactly that video.  To pass audio you would need a S/PDIF cable to go from your soundcard to your graphics card in order to transmit audio through HDMI.  Your best bet would be to get a [cord](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=102&cp_id=10218&cs_id=1021804&p_id=665&seq=1&format=2) to run from your headphone jack to the tv.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the alsa drivers for your distro version:
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages

Reboot and the HDMI option should appear in Sound Settings.